# PHP - json_decode() of a JSON string is null

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm calling this line in my browser:

```
example.com/save.php?params={"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}
```

and here's my **save.php** code:

```
<?php 
include 'Config.php';

    $getJSON = $_GET['params'];
    echo 'getJSON: '.$getJSON.'<br><br>';

    $updateArr = json_decode($getJSON, true);
    echo 'UPDATE_ARR: ' .$updateArr; //<-- it prints 'null'...

    $jsonStr = file_get_contents("Users.json");
    // Decode the JSON string into a PHP array.
    $objects = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

    array_push($objects, $updateArr);

    // Encode the array back into a JSON string and save it.
    $jsonData = json_encode($objects);
    file_put_contents("Users.json", $jsonData);

    // echo data
    echo 'JSON DATA: ' .$jsonData;
?>
```

The problem is this code makes my **User.json** file 'null', it removes all objects in it, in fact, the `echo 'UPDATE_ARR: ' .$updateArr;` returns null.
I would need to decode my `$getJSON` string into a PHP array, as I do for my **User.json** file (the `$jsonStr`), but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much!

Comment: so what i pass after ‘params=‘ is not a String?

Comment: You can use json_last_error() to determine the exact nature of the error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code and tested at my side it's working now. Please try it.

```
  <?php 
    include 'Config.php'; 
     if(!empty($_GET['params'])){
    $getJSON = $_GET['params'];
    echo 'getJSON: '.$getJSON.'<br><br>';

    $updateArr = json_decode($getJSON, true);
    echo 'UPDATE_ARR: ';print_r($updateArr); //<-- it prints 'null'...

    $jsonStr = file_get_contents("Users.json");
    // Decode the JSON string into a PHP array.
    $objects = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

    array_push($objects, $updateArr);

    // Encode the array back into a JSON string and save it.
    $jsonData = json_encode($objects);
    file_put_contents("Users.json", $jsonData);

    // echo data
    echo 'JSON DATA: ' .$jsonData;
}else{
    echo 'Params is empty';
}
```

This is the outcome of `users.json` file after refreshing many times:

**getJSON: {"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}
UPDATE_ARR: Array ( [objID] => i8O0FRuGEr [username] => johndoe [password] => 123456 [email] => j@doe.com [followedBy] => Array ( [0] => john [1] => sarah ) ) JSON DATA: {"ID":"i8O0FRuGEr","user_name":"johndoe","pass":123456,"email_id":"j@doe.com","followed_By":["john","sarah"],"0":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"1":null,"2":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"3":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"4":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"5":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"6":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"7":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"8":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}}**

After using your users.json file:

**[{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}]**

Comment: oh, so it was a matter of wrong echoing :) thanks so much, it works now!

Comment: Yes, you were trying to echo array as a string `.$updateArr; `

Comment: i don’t know why but it still adds a null object in my User.json file.»

Comment: The same code as I updated? Let me check it again at my side.

Comment: Yes, it's adding null second time. The reason is that it adds null for duplicate data.

Comment: see this my users.json file {"ID":"i8O0FRuGEr","user_name":"johndoe","pass":123456,"email_id":"j@doe.com","followed_By":["john","sarah"],"0":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},"1":null,"2":{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}}

Comment: if i refresh the page, it adds null object to my json file

Comment: can share your users.json file.

Comment: Are you using the same code as I updated? It's working fine as I tested.

Comment: this is what i get: getJSON: {"objID":"i8O0FRuGEt","username":"sarahdoe","password":sfagsdgfdsg,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}  UPDATE_ARR: JSON DATA: [{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]},null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

Comment: ARe you using same URL as save.php?params={"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}

Comment: Okay, I have also updated code. Now it will make sense for null. Please try this updated code

Answer (score 1):

this is no JSON string, while you won't properly `urlencode()` the query-string.
`die(urlencode('{"objID":"i8O0FRuGEr","username":"johndoe","password":123456,"email":"j@doe.com","followedBy":["john","sarah"]}'));`

^ append the above PHP output as `params=`.

rather proper would be, to `POST` the `JSON` as the content.

Answer (score 1):

It seems $getJson is null.

check its value using var_dump function or print_r function.

```
var_dump($getJson); // see what is the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) states that `json_decode()` returns NULL if the string cannot be decoded. Most likely it is a syntax error originating from bad url encoding.

Why are you json encoding url parameters in the first place? URL encoding is the accepted way to pass params in urls.

EDIT:

```
print_r($updateArr);
```

Shows a correct json, thus the problem is elsewhere

There are several other issues with your code.

1. `echo 'UPDATE_ARR: ' .$updateArr;` throws Notice: Array to string conversion  on line 6. Depending on your PHP version and configuration, your NULL could be printed because of bad typecasting in `echo`.
2. Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given on line 12. Check if your users.json file exists and is correct.

---